# how to use linq2sql table as base class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, unit-testing

I am trying to create some methods (GetContent and SaveContent) to extend a linq2sql DataClass

Apparently I am misusing "this" because the code fails on 
    dbo.docs.InsertOnSubmit(this);

my test code goes like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var newProfile = new profile();
    newProfile.GetContent();
    newProfile.saveProfile();

}
```

the class library like this:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public partial class doc // extends class created by linq2sql
    {
        public int doc_ii { get; set; }    
    }
    public class profile : doc  // extends doc class with get and save
    {
        public void GetContent()
        {
            this.url = "http://";
            this.content = "<html><head>...</head>,</html>";
        }
        public void SaveProfile()
        {
            var dbo = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                                            // NullReference
            dbo.docs.InsertOnSubmit(this);  // not set to an instance of an object.
                                            //
            dbo.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception detail

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Data.Linq
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity)
       at ClassLibrary1.profile.SaveProfile() in t:\TRACKER_sln\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\profile.cs:line 26
       at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in t:\TRACKER_sln\ClassLibrary1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 15
  InnerException:
```

Locals like in "image below" indicates that the base class is wrapped up as this.base, but dbo.docs.InsertOnSubmit(this.base); generates an "identifier expected, base is a keyword" error

(not enough reputation points to post image)

Comment: You're going to leak memory doing this.  You should use `using` to create your `DataContext` instance.

Comment: Robert, docs does exist and I can see data members. Bobson, googling to see what you mean by that.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.  *What* is null? `dbo`? `docs`? `this`? A property of `this`?  My guess is the last one, but there's no way to be sure right now.